# Converting PDF to EPS results in low resolution rasterization

Tags: graphics, pdf, conversion, eps, gnuplot

I have a problem with image converting for scientific manuscript. I have been using `gnuplot` to make graphs, using TikZ terminal, and finally generating the figure as a PDF with LaTeX. It results in a nice vector graphic image, in PDF file format (PDFLaTeX). The problem is that publishers ask for images in EPS format. When I try to convert my PDF with `Imagemagick` or `pdf2ps`, I get a low resolution rasterized image. But as far as I know eps is also a vector graphic format. I tried to set the resolution for conversion, but I get the same low resolution image. Is there a way to convert my vector graphic PDF to vector graphic EPS? Or anyone knows a way to export in eps from `gnuplot` with LaTeX typesetting/fonts?

Thanks,

Comment: I thought, the TikZ terminal should also allow to compile to eps, but that doesn't work for me. Otherwise you can use the `epslatex` and the `cairolatex eps` terminal to generate eps output graphics with LaTeX text.

Comment: Use `pdftops` rather than `convert` (from ImageMagick).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `pdftops` rather than `convert` (from ImageMagick). The command is

```
pdftops -f <first-page> -l <last-page> -eps <input.pdf> <output.eps>
```

For example,

```
pdftops -f 4 -l 4 -eps input.pdf output.pdf
```

### Simulator

Try the following to diagnose your problem.

```
% simulator.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{input.tex}
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
This is a TikZ output.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz\fill[red] (0,0) ellipse (3pt and 5pt); is an ellipse. 
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex input}
\immediate\write18{pdftops -f 1 -l 1 -eps input.pdf output.eps}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
I am importing EPS image.\\
\includegraphics{output}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compile the code above with

```
latex -shell-escape simulator
dvips simulator
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None simulator.ps
```

As  `ps2pdf` sometimes rotates the output automatically, please use `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` to prevent it from doing such an unwanted rotation.

If you are using Windows, use `#` instead of `=` in `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` because `=` has a special meaning for batch files in Windows.

### Very important notes

If you use `opacity` in your TikZ code (PSTricks code as well), for example,

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
This is a TikZ output.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz\fill[red,fill opacity=.5] (0,0) ellipse (3pt and 5pt); is an ellipse. 
\end{document}
```

then you will get a rasterized output as follows.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem with `pdftops` or `pdf2ps` as with `convert`.

Comment: Ok, it works. `pdftops` is the solution. Thank you very much. I thought `pdftops` is not working because I only looked at the eps in an image viewer. When I included it in a latex file and generated the pdf with `pdflatex`, I got perfect result. Thanks again!

Comment: For those coming to this answer unaware of the provenance of `pdftops`, it belongs to the `xpdf` package. macOS users can install it using homebrew: `brew install xpdf`